# Is there any another easy way to authenticate alexa skill rather than using userpool in cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a skill for technical help its a question answer type of skill which uses dynamodb for storing the answers and want to authenticate my skill using amazon login provided by AWS cognito but finding difficulty to do that.
i have created a demo skill hello world greeter which if invoked returns hello world the code is given below. i want to authenticate this skill using cognito but confused where to add and how to add the token handler code which is following and also having difficulty to show login card in alexa skill.
for cognito i have referred this site
https://medium.com/@ankit81008/alexa-accountlinking-cognito-74a29243b1ca

```js
//hello world greeter code
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  switch (event.request.type) {
    case "LaunchRequest":
      context.succeed(generateResponse(buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to Hello World Greeter.", false)))
      break;
    case "IntentRequest":
      switch (event.request.intent.name) {
        case "GreetHelloWorld":
          context.succeed(generateResponse(buildSpeechletResponse("Hello World", true)))
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

```js
//handler function code
if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken === undefined) {
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
.speak("to start using this skill, please use the companion app to authenticate")
.reprompt("to start using this skill, please use the companion app to authenticate")
.withLinkAccountCard()
.getResponse();
}
```

Comment: If you need account linking then oauth and cognito are the only way to do this.

Comment: i did in cognito and user token is also generated in developer console but not getting how to to fetch the authenticated user data from Cognito userpool. @NinadGaikwad